# Check if cookie exist otherwise redirect to url IIS

Tags: iis, iis-8.5

I would like to set IIS Redirection for a URL based on HTTP_COOKIE

cookie-name is `Token` and value is dynamic.

I tried below rules but each of them gave me errors -

```
<rule name="redirect based by cookie" stopProcessing="true">
<match url=".*" />
<conditions>
    <add input="{HTTP_COOKIE}" pattern="_xx=HCjdskfds==" />
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="xxx.yyy.com" />
</conditions>
<action type="Redirect" url="http://zzz.kkk.com/{R:0}" />
</rule>

<rule name="Route Base On Cookie" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="^(.*)" />
<conditions>
   <add input="{HTTP_COOKIE}" pattern="foo=(.*?);" />
</conditions>
<action type="Rewrite" url="http://{C:1}/{R:0}" />
</rule>
```

both of them above rule will give error on every url on my domain

[image: error description]

What i'm trying here is to redirect if that page doesn't contain cookie `Token` to error page/ Login page

Thanks in advance........

Comment: Learn FRT so that you can check further, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules

Comment: Will you get same error when you access the redirected URL directly？Your rule works fine on my side, so it should have nothing to do with your URL. Please post the detailed error message in failed request tracing log. You could view the report by opening  C:\inetpub\logs\FailedReqLogFiles\W3SVC<siteID> with IE.

Comment: @JokiesDing there is no files generated in C:\inetpub\logs\FailedReqLogFiles

Comment: Have you enabled the logging in edit tracing->enable? Besides, if the you have already enabled the rule. Did you see that request in C:\Windows\System32\LogFiles\HTTPERR?

Answer (score 1):

Goal: Redirect user if a cookie is NOT present in their request.

Solution:

- Add to web.config for IIS at root of project
- match every url
- Assumes cookie is `CookieName=any_value`
- Matching pattern uses regex to check cookie name with any value
- use `negate="true"` as a not operator; if cookie is NOT found
- `redirectType` is optional. Default is 301, `Found` is 302.

```xml
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>

        <rule name="Redirect if Cookie is present" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTP_COOKIE}" pattern="CookieName=*" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.my-domain.com/login" redirectType="Found" />
        </rule>

      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

This rule is basically a wildcard for a cookie with the name `CookieName` so that if a cookie with that name has any value at all (it exists), then you wont be redirected. If the cookie is NOT found, you will be redirected.

One caveat is that there's no way to identify an HttpOnly cookie vs a browser-set cookie... :(

Sources:

- [URL Rewrite Module Configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/url-rewrite-module-configuration-reference)